# NSCameraUsageDescription crash on launch agent, OS Mojave

Tags: swift, avfoundation, macos-mojave

I have a launch agent which request camera access. When I run app from Xcode, camera access popup appears. But when I export app and launch from "Applications" app does not shows a popup and crashes with following message.

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data

Note : I have added `NSCameraUsageDescription` in launch agent apps' info.plist.

In my `viewDidLoad()` method I am checking for camera permission.

```
if #available(OSX 10.14, *) {

        switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .audio) {
        case .authorized: // The user has previously granted access to the camera.
            NSLog("Audio Permission granted")

        case .notDetermined: // The user has not yet been asked for camera access.
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .audio) { granted in
                if granted {
                    NSLog("Audio Permission granted")

                } else {
                    NSLog("Audio Permission not granted11")
                }
            }

        case .denied: // The user has previously denied access.

            NSLog("Audio Permission not granted")
            return
        case .restricted: // The user can't grant access due to restrictions.
            NSLog("Audio Permission Not granted 1")
            return
            default:
            print("ss")
            return
        }
    } else {
        NSLog("OS Version < 10.14")

    }
```

Comment: Ever find a solution?

Comment: Yes, I have to manually open Launch agent. Once it is launched, I asked for camera permission in Appdelegate. It worked.